# Is the following possible in PowerShell: "Select-Object <Property>.<SubProperty>"?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-4.0

The scenario: I'm using Select-Object to access properties of a piped object, and one of those properties is itself an object.  Let's call it PropertyObject.  I want to access a property of that PropertyObject, say Property1.  Is there any nice and clean way of accessing Property1, along the lines of:

```
...| select-object PropertyObject.Property1
```

While experimenting I can only get it to work if I do something like:

```
...| select-object {$_.PropertyObject.Property1}
```

and if I want to display it with a decent column name it gets even messier:

```
...| select-object @{Name="Property1"; Expression={$_.PropertyObject.Property1}}
```

Given how clean and concise PowerShell is in general, I can't help thinking I'm missing something and there should be a cleaner way of accessing a property of a property.  Is there?

**EDIT:**  As requested by Matt, here is the concrete example:

I'm reading an XML file, Books3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date inprint="false">2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
      <publisher>
        <name>Simon and Schuster</name>
        <country>USA</country>
        <city>New York</city>
      </publisher>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date inprint="true">2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
      <publisher>
        <name>HarperCollins</name>
        <country>USA</country>
        <city>New York</city>
      </publisher>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date inprint="false">2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
      <publisher>
        <name>Macmillan</name>
        <country>United Kingdom</country>
        <city>London</city>
      </publisher>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Code to load XML into XmlDocument:

```
$filePath = "C:\Temp\books3.xml"
$xmlDoc = new-object xml
$xmlDoc.load($filePath)
```

Attempting to read details for each book:

```
$xmlDoc.catalog.book | select author, title, publisher.name
```

Result:

```
author                     title                      publisher.name
------                     -----                      --------------
Gambardella, Matthew       XML Developer's Guide
Ralls, Kim                 Midnight Rain
Corets, Eva                Maeve Ascendant
```

Comment: What is your powershell version? If its 3.0 you can just `$object.PropertyObject.Property1` else you would just chain the selects `select PropertyObject | select Property1`. You might need some expands in there but that is the jist. It all depends on the props

Comment: I made a minor update but I don't think it is the answer you are looking for. Extracting a single property is easier than the object output you are looking for. `Select` is the way to go for this. You could clean it up by moving the hash to a single variable but it does not change the code needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be easier if you had something actual repeatable for us to test but we can fake that with `Get-Item`s return.

```
(Get-Item C:\temp\logoutput).Parent.Name
```

`.Parent` is actually a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object. I use PowerShell 3.0 dot notation to get the `name` of the `parent`

The same result can be acquired by chaining the `select` calls

```
Get-Item C:\temp\logoutput | select -expand Parent | Select -Expand name
```

This of course would work in PowerShell 2.0 but is not a terse and the 3.0 version.

**Post Question Edit**

Not sure what you are hoping for. What you have does work at extracting sub properties the way you have it. I can only offer an alternate approach that might be more intuitive and friendly but the result is the same.

```
$xml.catalog.book | ForEach-Object{
    $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty "PublisherName" $_.publisher.name -PassThru}
```

Of course you might still need to use `select` to get your output restricted to the properties you need but it is another option.

Comment: I think your Post Question-Edit answers my question: I can't do something like `select author, title, publisher.name` and I have to do something a bit more complicated to get the publisher name.  I'm learning what does and doesn't work with PowerShell and that's really what I wanted to find out.  Cheers.

Answer (score 50):

You can use [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties). A short form would allow for this:

```
$xmlDoc.catalog.book | select author, title, {$_.publisher.name}
```

If the property names are important you need to add them in.

```
$xmlDoc.catalog.book | select author, title, @{N="PublisherName";E={$_.publisher.name}}
```

Where N is short for name and E is short for expression.

Comment: This actually answers OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

I too was on the hunt for how to accomplish a select of an object's sub-property. In my case it was in order to export a DNS Server's Zone data. I'll share the guts on what I used to accomplish my goal and this posting here helped!

To do what you were looking for specifically try modifying your code as follows:

```
$xmlDoc.catalog.book | Select Author, Title, -Expand Publisher | Select Author, Title, Name | Sort Author | FT -auto
```

Based on the table output you provided the above should work. It worked for me which you'll see below.

This script worked great for what I needed and is a blend of different ideas. Hopefully it works for someone else.

```
$Zones = @(Get-DnsServerZone)
ForEach ($Zone in $Zones) {
    Write-Host "`n$($Zone.ZoneName)" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    $Data = New-Object System.Object
    $Data = $Zone | Get-DnsServerResourceRecord
    $Data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ZoneName" -Value $Zone.ZoneName
    $Data += $Data
    $Data | Select-Object ZoneName, HostName, RecordType -Expand RecordData | Select ZoneName, HostName, RecordType, IPv4Address, HostNameAlias, NameServer, PrimaryServer, ExpireLimit, MinimumTimeToLive, RefreshInterval, ResponsiblePerson, RetryDelay, SerialNumber, DomainName, Port, Priority, Weight | Sort RecordType, HostName | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$($Zone.ZoneName).csv"
}
```

The Yellow Foreground is handy when you're looking at the output prior to export. Just put the `}` right after `HostName` and before `| Export-Csv` like this: `... Sort RecordType, HostName }`

Comment: Tried it but got the following error: `Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'publisher'.`  I wonder if it's because the book object is of type System.Xml.XmlElement?